# Un substantif du verbe « vouer »

Tags: vocabulaire, substantivation

Je souhaiterais connaître le nom qui correspond à « vouer » dans le sens « vouer un culte ».

Par exemple : Il voue un culte à blabla → Sa *vouetion* (?!) au culte de blabla

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Il me semble que le mot que tu cherches est [*dévouement*](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/devouement).  Mais il est aussi possible d'utiliser [*dévotion*](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/devotion) qui est un dévouement à un culte (et en particulier mais pas uniquement à ses aspects rituels, aspects qui sont seuls présents au pluriel *ses dévotions*).

> Il voue un culte à Marie.

Peut devenir

> Sa dévotion à Marie.

ou

> Son dévouement au culte de Marie.

Avec parfois des nuances (p.e. dans un emploi ironique ou pour suggérer un excès, je n'utiliserais que la première forme).

Comment: *Dévouement à* dans le sens de *vouer un culte à*, vraiment ?

Answer (score 5):

Si c'est le substantif que tu cherches, c'est : *la dévotion*.

Comment: Ca vient surtout de voeu non ?

Comment: Je pensais que dévotion c'était uniquement pour dévouer (qui est subtilement différent de vouer). J'en déduis donc qu'il n'y a pas de substantif dédié au verbe vouer ?

Comment: @T__O Oui, techniquement parlant, c'est bien *voeu* qui est le substantif historique, mais il a cessé d'être employé comme tel, et c'est bien *dévotion* qui a pris en charge, en plus de son propre sens initial, *l'acte de se vouer à*.

Comment: On ne dira pas "Sa dévotion au culte de Marie" mais sa "dévotion à Marie".

Comment: @Unfrancophone Oui, tu as raison, ce qui prouve que *dévotion* contient déjà implicitement l'idée de culte, ce qui ferait de l'expression *dévotion au culte de ...* un pléonasme.

Answer (score 1):

Le *vœu*, au sens de « prononcer un vœu », correspond au sens et aux racines latines mais son usage est assez limité, en dehors des vœux monastiques/chevaleresques.

On le trouve toutefois pour Dorian Grey, ce n'est donc pas « interdit » ([reférence](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22son%20v%C5%93u%22%20dorian%20grey)).